# How many tcp connections when I make 100 http connections?

Tags: http, tcp

During the last week's interview,the interviewer asked me the question.I read a lot of information,but I don't know this,either.

Answer (score 0):

When you make 100 HTTP **connections** it will do 100 TCP **connections**. If you do 100 HTTP **requests** instead it depends on the specific implementation and configuration of client and server - it might be one TCP connection for all 100 requests, it might be 100 TCP with each connection handling 1 request or it might be anything in between.